# Apache rewrite: How to detect & do 301 trailing slash-redirect on my own?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

### Short version:

I got a request (no trailing slash)

```
mydomain.com/slides/sessionOne
```

**How can I figure out in a *RewriteCond* if `'_slides/sessionOne'` exists and is a directory?** If so, append a trailing `/` (but do not prepend a `_`) and redirect `[R=301]`.

### Long version:

I have a fairly empty webroot:

```
.htaccess
_slides  (dir)
_site    (dir)
```

and a .htaccess that almost does what I want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# directly accessing an _underscore-Folder? – Forbid!
RewriteRule ^_ - [R=403,END]

# AAA    

RewriteRule ^slides/(.+)$  _slides/$1 [END]

# prevent _site prepend before _slides
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_(site|slides)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  _site/$1 [END]
```

- any URL under `slides/` will find it's stuff in the `_slides` folder
- any other url will go and look inside the `_site` folder
- direct access to both underscore-folders is prevented

Directory-URLs with trailing slash work fine, just like files: For example `slides/presentation1/` will internally find `_slides/presentation1/index.html` w/o any visible URL change, as it should.

**My trouble: Directory-URLs without trailing slash:**

- `slides/presentation1` will first get (internal, non-visible) rewritten to `_slides/presentation1`
- since the slash is missing, but there is a directoy of that name, Apache automatically makes a visible 301 redirect, sending me to `_slides/presentation1/`.

But I do not want to reveal the underscore-Folders, and this (correctly) gets caught by my check.

So, I would need at the “AAA” position is in pseudo-code:

```
URI has no trailing slash
AND there exists a directory either under _slides oder _site?
(peeking for it)

==> make a 301 redirect!
but no underscores prepended, just a trailing slash attached...
```

**Here's my attempt (at the AAA position), but it's just not working:**

```
# directory w/o trailing slash inside _slides/ ?
# ==> attach slash and 301
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteCond _slides/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond _site/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Toughie, but I found a way:

1. generate a (server-absolute) path to peek for a valid directory (the `-d` does not care, if your path has 0,1 or even multiple trailing slashes). For generation I use rewrite rules, that don't rewrite anything (“`-`”), but store what I need in an [env var](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e). Only do that for URLs in question, that is: w/o trailing (→`[^/]`).
2. Otherwise the env var remains empty. (one of the two, certainly will. Can't match both.)
3. for applicable (aka non-empty) Env-Vars, check if they are is a directory, if so, append trailing slash, do a 301. (to make the slash-append visible. Like any webservers does..., just under tougher circumstances...).
4. if there was no 301 (resp. that run happened before), redirect as described in the question.

**Code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# already on _underscore-Folder? – Forbid!
RewriteRule ^_ - [R=404,L,END]

# at most one of the two will become valid
RewriteRule ^(slides/.+[^/])$ - [E=slidesPeek:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}_$1]
RewriteRule ^(?!slides/)(.*[^/])$ - [E=sitePeek:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}_site/$1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:slidesPeek} !^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:slidesPeek} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0/ [R=301,L,END]

RewriteCond %{ENV:sitePeek} !^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:sitePeek} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0/ [R=301,L,END]

RewriteRule ^slides/(.+)$  _slides/$1 [L,END]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_(site|slides)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  _site/$1 [END]
```

**Bonus 8-)** Useful for testing and debugging:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!DEBUG)\w+$ /DEBUG?%{DOCUMENT_ROOT} [R=301,END]
```

**Caveat:**

- Flag `[L]` means: stop for the rest of this .htacess-file (but possible do additional rounds from start. On 301 redirects and on internal rewrites)
- Flag `[END]` means: No additional rounds... (except for 301, which inevitably starts the whole thing). **[END] does NOT imply [L]. Without [L], rules that follow would still be applied, just no additional rounds**

Something, that one won't notice on more trivial cases.

**Just for reference:** (mind all the slashes)

```
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}
/is/htdocs/user12345678/www.mydomain.de/

%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
/is/htdocs/user12345678/www.mydomain.de/abc

%{REQUEST_URI}
uri=/abc
```

Preceeding slashes are a **constant pain** by the way: `RewriteRule` get's the URL without initial slash, whereas `%{REQUEST_URI}` has one...

I honestly no longer understand, why the seconds-last line is needed. But deletion gets me 404s...

---

Advice:

Browsers notoriously cache your prior 301-redirects (keep sending you there again, without checking.)

Thus either you need to keep cleaning caches all the time *or* you do your testing from the command line, i.e.

```
cd someTemporaryFolder
wget http://mywhateverurl.com 2>&1
```

resp.

```
wget http://mywhateverurl.com 2>&1 | grep Location:
```